# does not have a member names 'subscript' - SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building a trivia app and I have made a class for creating questions. I also made a function that will load when viewDidLoad().

```
 class Question{
    var quizQuestion : String = ""
    var firstAnswer : String = ""
    var secondAnswer : String = ""
    var thirdAnswer : String = ""
    var fourthAnswer : String = ""
    var rightAnswer : Int = 0

init(question:String, answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, correctAnswer:Int)
{

    self.quizQuestion = question
    self.firstAnswer = answerOne
    self.secondAnswer = answerTwo
    self.thirdAnswer = answerThree
    self.fourthAnswer = answerFour
    self.rightAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
}


let one = Question(question: "What was the first planet to be discovered using a telescope, in 1781?", answerOne: "Mars", answerTwo: "Jupiter", answerThree: "Uranus", answerFour: "Mercury", correctAnswer: 3)
```

my initialState() function

```
 func initialState() {
    var firstQuestion: AnyObject = arrayOfQuestions[0]

    currentQuestion = 0



    questionLabel.text = "\(firstQuestion[0])"

    //Setting the buttons text
    firstAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion[1])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    secondAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion[2])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    thirdAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion[3])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    fourthAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion[4])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

When I want to set the buttons text to the index of the question and answers, it says 'Question' does not have a member named 'subscript', which makes no sense to me. When I run the app, everything is set to "nil."

Can anyone help with this? 
Please explain your answers as I am trying to learn the language and the errors.

Comment: Well "Question" isn't a collection type, and you can only use subscript on collection types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure the code to use an answer array. It will be easier to manage. Also give the correct answer as the index of the array.

```
class Question{
    var quizQuestion : String = ""
    var answers : Array<String> = Array()
    var rightAnswer : Int = 0

    init(question:String, answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, correctAnswer:Int)
    {
        self.quizQuestion = question
        self.answers.append(answerOne)
        self.answers.append(answerTwo)
        self.answers.append(answerThree)
        self.answers.append(answerFour)
        self.rightAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
}

let one = Question(question: "What was the first planet to be discovered using a telescope, in 1781?",
answerOne: "Mars", answerTwo: "Jupiter", answerThree: "Uranus", answerFour: "Mercury", correctAnswer: 3)



func initialState() {
    var firstQuestion: Question = arrayOfQuestions[0]

    questionLabel.text = "\(firstQuestion.quizQuestion)"

    //Setting the buttons text
    firstAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.answers[0])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    secondAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.answers[1])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    thirdAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.answers[2])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    fourthAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.answers[3])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Comment: Except there's only four answers for every question so this isn't really necessary...but in practice, yes this would be a good idea.  For this specific instance, either way is probably ok, and his method may actually be more readable.

Comment: yeah but if he needs to show the right answers in a different page, the current method will cause ugly code.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got it to work! I appreciate it. I know now how to format it for it to work... thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

```
questionLabel.text = "\(firstQuestion.quizQuestion)"

//Setting the buttons text
firstAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.firstAnswer)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
secondAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.secondAnswer)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
thirdAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.thirdAnswer)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
fourthAnswer.setTitle("\(firstQuestion.fourthAnswer)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When i do \(firstQuestion.quizQuestion), it says AnyObject does not have a member named quizQuestion.

Comment: Why do you initiate firstQuestion as an array?  If you make it of the class 'Question' this will work